# pdfmake.js Two different absolutePositions within the background function

Tags: background, pdfmake

I try to set two text elements in a header with the background function on two different positions. But it didn't work. (Only the last one wins) Is there a way to get it fixed?

```
background: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
                        return {
                            text: 'pagenumber ' + currentPage,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            absolutePosition: {
                                x: 50,
                                y: 60
                            },

                             text: 'printtime: ' + moment(this.result[0].time).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"),
                             fontSize: 12,
                             absolutePosition: {
                                x: 600,
                                y: 80
                             }
                        }
                    },
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have two elements, you have to return Array. Try this:

```js
background: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
  return [{
      text: 'pagenumber ' + currentPage,
      fontSize: 12,
      absolutePosition: {
        x: 50,
        y: 60
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'printtime: ' + moment(this.result[0].time).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"),
      fontSize: 12,
      absolutePosition: {
        x: 600,
        y: 80
      }
    }
  }]
},
```